# Can all Chern numbers be interpreted as the degree of some maps?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

In some physics applications, I am aware that the first Chern number and the second can be interpreted as the degree of some maps.

For example, the first Chern number appears in topological insulators, e.g. in the Haldane models, where it is the degree of the map from a torus $T^2$ (the first Brillouin zone) to a 2-sphere $S^2$.

A similar interpretation is also found for the 2nd Chern number.
In the theory of instantons, i.e. Yang-Mills theory in $R^4$, there is
$$
w(g)=\frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int_{S^3}\textrm{Tr}\left[{g^{-1}dg\wedge g^{-1}dg\wedge g^{-1}dg}\right]$$

where $g:S^3\rightarrow SU(2)$ is a map (a gauge transformation), and **$w$ is the winding of this map**. $g^{-1}dg$ is Maurier-Cartan form. In physics this is called the Pontryagin index, winding number, Instanton action, Wess-Zumino-Witten (WZW) action, etc. This term is also part of the non-Abelian Chern-Simons action.

This term is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\int_{S^4}\textrm{Tr}\left[F\wedge F\right]
$$
where $F = dA+A\wedge A$ is the curvature, $A$ is the gauge potential (local connection form).
This is the second Chern number.

**Question**:

I am not sure if the interpretation of Chern numbers as the degree of maps is true for all Chern numbers in general. In other words, are the above just coincidences? Is there a universal interpretation such that the $n$th Chern number can be interpreted as the degree of some maps from some $M$ to some $N$, the structure of which depend on $n$? Is such interpretation important (in the sense that it is a common perspective in learning Chern classes)?

Comment: This question would be much easier to answer if you included more details.

Comment: @QuaereVerum Sorry if the question is not clear. I am from a physics background is just learning the mathematics of characteristic classes. Could you please elaborate on which details should be added?

Comment: In what sense can the first and second Chern numbers be interpreted as degrees of maps?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese see edits above, thanks!

Comment: I meant the same as @MichaelAlbanese. I appreciate that you updated the question. I would still ask you to add some extra details. Where does the $2$-torus come from in this story? I am unaware of a construction which, for any arbitrary vector bundle $E\to X$, produces a map $T^2\to S^2$ whose degree is the first Chern number of $E$.

Comment: And, while you're at it, why are you talking about "all Chern characters" rather than Chern classes or Chern numbers? I personally think about Chern classes in terms of intersection theory and degeneracy loci, not degrees.

Comment: @QuaereVerum see further edits, with context and more details added.

Comment: @TedShifrin see edits with more context and details added. I thought Chern characters = Chern numbers?

Comment: No, the Chern character is built formally: If you split a bundle $E$ as a sum of line bundles whose first Chern classes are $\theta_1,\dots, \theta_k$, then $\text{ch}(E) = \sum e^{\theta_j}$. Unless Chern classes, it has nice multiplicative behavior for the tensor product of bundles and is related to the Todd classes of the bundle.

Comment: in general chern classes are pullbacks in cohomology. In particular, there is a space [$BU(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space_for_U(n)) that basically has the chern classes. In your case, (small dimension) we can regard the classifying map for the tangent bundle on $T^2$ as a map $T^2 \to \mathbb CP^\infty$, but really this is just a map to the two skeleton of $CP^\infty$ which is $S^2$. Then pulling back the cohomology class corresponding to $S^2$ is basically just taking the degree of the classifying map

Comment: sorry that I don't know any physics. I would suggest maybe looking at Allen Hatcher's book https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html

Comment: @TedShifrin I see so the integral of Chern form is called the Chern number but Chern character is different from this.